# Docker: Expose running container to host

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a running MySQL container that I have import a lot of data in it (took me a few hours).

Now I want to query the data from this container using a GUI application (DBeaver) on my host. Is there a way that I can expose the network of the running container to host so I can connect to it?

I've been looking around and the most promising option so far is to run `docker run` a new container with `-p` tag `3306:3306` but when I do that, all the data imported is gone.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Oh, by the way, I don't know why this question was down voted, it's a completely legit question (damn it...)

1. Find the ID of the container `docker ps`
2. Grab that ID, run `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' <container-id>`
3. From the result, I know that the volume of that container is located here: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/simple_wiki_container_devcontainer_my-datavolume/_data`
4. `docker run -p 3306:3306 --name new_mysql_with_data -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=a_strong_password -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/simple_wiki_container_devcontainer_my-datavolume/_data:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:lateset`

Now I can connect with `mysql-client` on host `0.0.0.0` on port `3306`.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new mysql image from running container and run the new image with exposed port . You can do that by using `docker commit`. Run the new image with exposed port, your data will be saved. use

```
 docker commit <CONTAINER_ID> mysql-with-data:latest
```

don't stop running container until commit is done –

Comment: thanks! where is the part in the command above that gets the port `3306` exposed?

Comment: I've tried this. But the data is not there...

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice, and I wouldn't recommend it here.  Of note, the standard Docker Hub database images are built in a way where committing the images never keeps their data (it is _always_ in a volume even if you haven't included a `docker run -v` option, and volumes are never committed).